# ¿Se puede cargar una librería en otra librería?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Me gustaría saber si es posible cargar una librería en otra librería en codeigniter.

Lo que sucede es que ando creando una librería para hacer menús, pero me gustaría tomar cosas de la librería session y usarla en la que estoy creando.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, solo tienes que agregar esto

```
class Tu_libreria{

    protected $CI;

    public function __construct($rules = array()){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        $this->CI->load->library('session');
    }
...
}
```